# Implementing clipping function using Keras backend

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, backend

I would like to implement a clipping function using Keras backend:

```
f(x) = 

x, if 0<x<1 
1, if x>1 
0, otherwise
```

I can do it in numpy as follows:

```
def myclip(x): 
    import numpy as np 

    return np.int64((x>=1)==True)+np.multiply(np.int64( np.logical_and(x>0, x<1)==True),x)
```

It could be

```
def myclipK(x): 

    from tensorflow.keras import backend as K 


    return K.int64((x>=1)==True)+K.multiply(np.int64( K.logical_and(x>0, x<1)==True),x)
```

But, we don't have things like K.int64 or K.multiply, or K.logical.

How can I do this

Comment: Why not use `K.clip()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Keras documentation, you cannot do it currently. Below are all the currently available functions:

```
_broadcast_normalize_batch_in_training
_fused_normalize_batch_in_training
_get_available_gpus
_get_current_tf_device
_GRAPH_LEARNING_PHASES
_GRAPH_UID_DICTS
_has_nchw_support
_is_current_explicit_device
_LOCAL_DEVICES
_MANUAL_VAR_INIT
_preprocess_conv1d_input
_preprocess_conv2d_input
_preprocess_conv3d_input
_preprocess_padding
_regular_normalize_batch_in_training
_SESSION
_TfDeviceCaptureOp
_to_tensor
abs
all
any
arange
argmax
argmin
batch_dot
batch_flatten
batch_get_value
batch_normalization
batch_set_value
bias_add
binary_crossentropy
cast
categorical_crossentropy
clear_session
clip
concatenate
constant
conv1d
conv2d
conv2d_transpose
conv3d
conv3d_transpose
cos
count_params
ctc_batch_cost
ctc_decode
ctc_label_dense_to_sparse
cumprod
cumsum
depthwise_conv2d
dot
dropout
dtype
elu
equal
eval
exp
expand_dims
eye
flatten
foldl
foldr
function
Function
gather
get_session
get_uid
get_value
get_variable_shape
gradients
greater
greater_equal
hard_sigmoid
identity
in_test_phase
in_top_k
in_train_phase
int_shape
is_keras_tensor
is_placeholder
is_sparse
is_tensor
l2_normalize
learning_phase
less
less_equal
local_conv1d
local_conv2d
log
logsumexp
manual_variable_initialization
map_fn
max
maximum
mean
min
minimum
moving_average_update
name_scope
ndim
normalize_batch_in_training
not_equal
one_hot
ones
ones_like
permute_dimensions
placeholder
pool2d
pool3d
pow
print_tensor
prod
py_all
py_any
py_slice
py_sum
random_binomial
random_normal
random_normal_variable
random_uniform
random_uniform_variable
relu
repeat
repeat_elements
reset_uids
reshape
resize_images
resize_volumes
reverse
rnn
round
separable_conv1d
separable_conv2d
set_learning_phase
set_session
set_value
shape
sigmoid
sign
sin
slice
softmax
softplus
softsign
sparse_categorical_crossentropy
spatial_2d_padding
spatial_3d_padding
sqrt
square
squeeze
stack
std
stop_gradient
sum
switch
tanh
temporal_padding
tile
to_dense
transpose
truncated_normal
update
update_add
update_sub
var
variable
zeros
zeros_like
```

Therefore, you can push your own implementation and contribute to Keras in github. Sad but true.

Comment: How about k.clip

Comment: ok, I assumed you wanted to know how you can "manually" create clipping function like you did in numpy. Therefore, I think my question answer what you asked originally

Comment: Thanks. Instead of waiting for keras, can I write it using tensorflow and use it in keras?

Comment: yes you can. But the thing is you asked for Keras backend and what one can understand is that you want to create backend irrelevant gradient clipping. That is, I understood that you want to create a function that would work for theano, pytorch, tensorflow or any other backend. That is the idea behind Keras backend. If your intention was to use tensorflow only, then it is rather strange you want to use Keras backend. I hope you get the idea

Comment: Yes, I agree. Now, given that I only need tensorflow, can we write it using tensorflow?

Comment: yes you can. but for this post, you have to accept or decline my post because I think I answered your original question

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of keras.backend functionality.

It has functionalities like clip(), sum(), greater_than etc.

You will have to arrange your equation using keras.backend and it should work.